# For which reasons we don't received data from facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook page and i am using **Graph API** to fetch the data. But I where i can find For which reasons we don't received data from **facebook** page.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: are asking about facebook policy? or you cant get data from facebook because of a bug in your code ?

Comment: @thomasbabuj - Thanks for reply.. I dont have any bug but i need all the reasons behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has several security features to protect people's information, to let people control what they share, and to let developers safely request access to this information.  Once user authorize your app, you will have access to user's data. User has the option to delete are edit the app permission (from accounts -> app setttings page).

[The Login Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/)

Check out this [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

Answer (score 1):

one reason I know is when the size of data being fetched is more than certain limit, though I don't know exactly what that size limit is.